# null BroadcasterFactory before Nettosphere initialization

Tags: atmosphere

I want to inject a BroadcasterFactory into a Publisher-style class before I have constructed my Nettosphere via it's builders. But a call to BroadcasterFactory.getDefault() returns null before it's initialized via the construction of my Nettosphere. I guess I could build a BroadcasterFactory myself first, but that seems to be messing with the Nettosphere construction process.

At a high level I want access to Broadcasters (1 per connection) from the backend in order to push individual messages to clients.

I could do my own map of broadcasters, but broadcasterfactory already does this and I don't really want to have to manage 2 stores of broadcasters.

Thanks :)

Comment: I haven't pursued solving this issue or trying jfarcand's idea below. I've come around to managing multiple references to the broadcasters and so manage my own map.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Atmosphere are you using?

Just tested with 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT and it worked.

I suspect they were a regression before.

Comment: I'm using nettosphere 2.0.0.RC1 which uses atmosphere-runtime 1.1.0.RC1, but I've actually come around to using my own map of sessions (i.e. broadcasters) for now. Many thanks for your reply!

Comment: I'll keep upgrading nettosphere as new releases appear in maven central :)